# How to compute the PDF of $Z=XY$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution

After the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684411/what-is-the-correct-way-of-compute-pdf-of-y-2x) I got, I'm interested in the case for computing the PDF of a random variable $Z=XY$, and $X, Y$ are independent. The [convolution of PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions#Introduction) describe the PDF of the sum of two random variables, if we go for the previous step before that result and substitute $y=z/x$ for this case ...

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,z/x)\ dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\ dx$$

but I don't think is right because this operation should be commutative, meaning:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\ dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\ dy$$

but if I applied the standard approach to demostrate that [convolution is commutative](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiB_IrJxr7-AhUqqJUCHYH4CMkQFnoECBgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ece.uvic.ca%2F%7Efrodo%2Fcourses%2Fece260%2Fvideo_lectures%2Fece260_2020_05_video_lecture_information_package%2Fslides_supplemental%2Ftheorem_4_1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2CDraiLZ89cZe12T54qIwq), I get something like:

Let $\tau=z/x,\quad x=z/\tau,\quad dx=(-z/\tau^2)d\tau$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,z/x)\ dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{x=-b}^{x=b}f_{X,Y}(x,z/x)\ dx$$

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{\tau=z/-b}^{\tau=z/b}f_{X,Y}(z/\tau,\tau)\left(-{z\over\tau^2}\right) d\tau=-z\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{\tau=z/-b}^{\tau=z/b}f_{X,Y}(z/\tau,\tau){d\tau\over\tau^2}$$

$$=-z\int_{0^-}^{0^+}f_{X,Y}(z/\tau,\tau){d\tau\over\tau^2}=0 $$

Comment: Use `$$\begin{align} A&=B\\ &=C\\ &=D.\end{align}$$` for $$\begin{align} A&=B\\ &=C\\ &=D.\end{align}$$

Comment: Is it part of a guideline? @Shaun

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your computation of the PDF of the product is wrong. Let's suppose, as you have tacitly done, that $X,Y$ have densities $f_X, f_Y$. We have that
$$\begin{align*}P(Z \leq z) &= P(XY \leq z) \\ &= P(XY \leq z, Y \leq 0) + P(XY \leq z, Y > 0) \\ &= P(X \geq z/Y, Y \leq 0) + P(X \leq z/Y, Y > 0) \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^0\int_{z/y}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy +  \int_{0}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{z/y} f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy\end{align*}$$ so we may differentiate (exchanging the derivative and the first integral) to get that
$$f_Z(z) = -\int_{-\infty}^0 f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\frac{dy}{y} + \int_0^\infty f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\frac{dy}{y} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\frac{dy}{|y|},$$ If you used $P(XY \leq z, X \leq 0) + P(XY \leq z, X > 0)$ instead you would get the symmetric $$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\frac{dx}{|x|}.$$

More directly in response to your posting, you make a mistake in the substiution. Since $y \mapsto z/x$ isn't well defined (let alone differentiable) on $(-\infty, \infty)$ so you can't just make this substiution. Instead (and I'm still handwaving to some extent, since really we should be taking limits to $0$ and $\infty$ everywhere, but this is implicit in the notation) you have to split the integral over $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$, as in the following (where I will take the correct expression for the PDF). Taking $y = \frac{z}{x}$ and $dy = -\frac{z}{x^2}dx$, we have that $\frac{dx}{x} = -\frac{dy}{y}$ and therefore
$$\begin{align*} f_Z(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\frac{dx}{|x|} \\ &= -\int_{-\infty}^0 f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\frac{dx}{x} + \int_{0}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\frac{dx}{x} \\ &= \int_{0}^{-\infty} f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\frac{dy}{y} - \int_{\infty}^0 f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\frac{dy}{y}\\ &= - \int_{-\infty}^{0} f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\frac{dy}{y} + \int_{0}^\infty f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\frac{dy}{y} \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z/y)f_Y(y)\frac{dy}{|y|} \end{align*}$$ as expected.

Comment: Thanks you for your complete answer. I understood everything :). Just a last question, do you know a module in python to compute this type of operation?

Comment: Can you say more explicitly what you mean by "this type of operation"?

Comment: There is convolution calculators online, I was thinking of there is the same "calculators" that evaluate that type of integral. Also, do you know how to evaluate by hand? I was thinking of an example where $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$ and given that the Heaviside unit function doesn't change of shape when scaling the argument, the PDF of $XY$ should be $\int_{(-\infty,\infty)}(1/|x|)dx$. Is that right?

Comment: Well probably not since $XY$ shouldn't be supported on all of $\mathbb R$. Hint: the pdf of $X \sim U(0, 1)$ is not $1$ on all of $\mathbb R$, but merely $1$ on $[0,1]$. So the real pdf is $\int 1_{x, z/x \in [0, 1]}\frac{dx}{x} = -\log(z)$ for $z \in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise (where the $1_{blah\ blah}$ is an indicator function).

Comment: And no, I generally don't know of a python library to compute this analytically, but in general you can just compute the pdf numerically pretty easily if you care about applications. I'm also sure that you can just input the integral by hand into some general software (e.g. Mathematica, or you could try SymPy if you like, but I never have) if you must.

Comment: Thanks for all your help 

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to look at it geometrically (assuming X and Y independent).  Then the distribution can be looked as the area of a subset on the unit square.  The easiest approach is to first get the cdf $P(XY\le z)=1-P(XY\gt z)$.  $P(XY\gt z)= \int\limits_z^1(\int\limits_\frac{z}{x}^1 dydx=\int\limits_z^1 (1-\frac{z}{x})dx=1-z+zlog(z)$, which is the area of the unit square between XY=z and XY=1.  The cdf is then $z-zlog(z)$ and the pdf is $-log(z)$  All this for $0\le z \le 1$.